# Kubernetes 1.7.7: how to enable Cron Jobs?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-acs

I've added `—-runtime-config=batch/v2alpha1=true` to the `kube-apiserver` config like so:

```
      ... other stuff
      command:
        - "/hyperkube"
        - "apiserver"
        - "--admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota"
        - "--address=0.0.0.0"
        - "--allow-privileged"
        - "--insecure-port=8080"
        - "--secure-port=443"
        - "--cloud-provider=azure"
        - "--cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/azure.json"
        - "--service-cluster-ip-range=10.0.0.0/16"
        - "--etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379"
        - "--etcd-quorum-read=true"
        - "--advertise-address=10.240.255.15"
        - "--tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.crt"
        - "--tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.key"
        - "--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/ca.crt"
        - "--service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.key"
        - "--storage-backend=etcd2"
        - "--v=4"
        - "—-runtime-config=batch/v2alpha1=true"
        ... etc
```

but after restarting the master `kubectl api-versions` still shows only `batch/v1`, no `v2alpha1` to be seen.

```
$ kubectl api-versions
apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
apps/v1beta1
authentication.k8s.io/v1
authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
authorization.k8s.io/v1
authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
autoscaling/v1
batch/v1
certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
extensions/v1beta1
networking.k8s.io/v1
policy/v1beta1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1alpha1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1
storage.k8s.io/v1
storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
v1
```

Here's my job definition:

```
kind: CronJob
apiVersion: batch/v2alpha1
metadata:
  name: mongo-backup
spec:
  schedule: "* */1 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
... etc
```

And the error I get when I try to create the job:

```
$ kubectl create -f backup-job.yaml                 
error: error validating "backup-job.yaml": error validating data: unknown object type schema.GroupVersionKind{Group:"batch", Version:"v2alpha1", Kind:"CronJob"}; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
$ kubectl create -f backup-job.yaml --validate=false
error: unable to recognize "backup-job.yaml": no matches for batch/, Kind=CronJob
```

What else do I need to do?

PS. this is on Azure ACS, I don't think it makes a difference though.

Comment: You restart the vm or the service? did the file still include your addition after the restart?

Comment: @itaysk yes, I restarted the entire VM. I checked the logs and I can see that it was started with the correct parameters.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the latest API versions here `apiVersion: batch/v1beta1` that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The latest Kubernetes [v1.21 Release Notes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/) states that:

> - The batch/v2alpha1 CronJob type definitions and clients are deprecated and removed. ([#96987](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/96987), [@soltysh](https://github.com/soltysh)) [SIG API
>   Machinery, Apps, CLI and Testing]

In that version you should use `apiVersion: batch/v1`, see the [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#example) below:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

[Notice that](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/):

> `CronJobs` was promoted to general availability in Kubernetes v1.21. If
> you are using an older version of Kubernetes, please refer to the
> documentation for the version of Kubernetes that you are using, so
> that you see accurate information. Older Kubernetes versions do not
> support the `batch/v1` CronJob API.

Answer (score -1):

There is an open issue for that on their github:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51939

I believe there is no other option but wait, right now
i'm actually stuck on the same issue